# Highlight multiple rows from a listbox based on two if condition in C#

Tags: c#, datetime, for-loop, listbox, highlight

I need to highlight in red the expiry dates which is due in 30 days. And highlight in yellow the dates which is lower than today. My program highlight just first row. I think I am wrong at the for loop.
This is my code:

```
string dateInString = con.read["Data_expirare"].ToString();

DateTime startDate = DateTime.Parse(dateInString);
DateTime expiryDate = startDate.AddDays(30);

for (int i = 0; i <= listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
{
    if (DateTime.Now >= expiryDate)
    {
        listView1.Items[i].BackColor = Color.Red;
    }
    if (DateTime.Now > startDate)
    {
        listView1.Items[i].BackColor = Color.Yellow;
    }
}
```

This is what my program return:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Swap the checks:

```
string dateInString = con.read["Data_expirare"].ToString();

DateTime startDate = DateTime.Parse(dateInString);
DateTime expiryDate = startDate.AddDays(30);

for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
{
    if (DateTime.Now > startDate)
    {
        listBox1.Items[i].BackColor = Color.Yellow;
    }
    if (DateTime.Now >= expiryDate)
    {
        listBox1.Items[i].BackColor = Color.Red;
    }
}
```

Comment: I try but still not working properly, just swap the color but only the first element is highlighted.

Comment: @xmi look at `i < listBox1.Items.Count` and in your example you use listBox1 and listView1 at the same time in the loop `for`. Your example can throw exception

Answer (score 0):

I try this, just red color without yellow:

for (int i = 0; i < listView1.Items.Count; i++)
{

```
                DateTime x = Convert.ToDateTime(listView1.Items[i].SubItems[1].Text);
                DateTime y = x.AddDays(30);
               /* if (DateTime.Now > x)
                {
                    listView1.Items[i].BackColor = Color.Yellow;

                }*/
                if (DateTime.Now >= y)
                {
                    listView1.Items[i].BackColor = Color.Red;

                }
            }
```